# Is there a way to produce a new variable, conditioned on different text values in two other variables in R Studio

Tags: r, variables, rstudio

I am looking for a function which allows me to produce a new variable, based on text values in two other variables.

Variable `x` has the text values `"both"` `"current"` `"no"` `"previous"` 
and variable `y` has the text values `"yes"` and `"no"`.

Now I want to create a variable `z` which has the text value yes, if the text value in the other variables is either `"both"` `"current"` `"previous"` or `"yes"` (so everything else than `"no"`).

Does such a function exist, I am sure it does, but I having digging for hours without finding anything suitable.

Any help appreciated - I am new to the forum, and apologies for not being able to give a data example, my dataset is simply to big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does this suit your case ?

```
# exemple data with all the cases possible.
df<- data.frame(x = rep(c('both','current','no','previous'),2),
                y = c(rep('yes',4),rep('no',4)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
#          x   y
# 1     both yes
# 2  current yes
# 3       no yes
# 4 previous yes
# 5     both  no
# 6  current  no
# 7       no  no
# 8 previous  no
#### EDIT ####
# new method corrected via the comments
df$z <- rep('yes',nrow(df))
df$z[df$x == 'no' & df$y == 'no'] <- 'no'
#          x   y   z
# 1     both yes yes
# 2  current yes yes
# 3       no yes yes
# 4 previous yes yes
# 5     both  no yes
# 6  current  no yes
# 7       no  no  no
# 8 previous  no yes

# Old method
# Here I change every row of df$z where df$x is not 'no' and df$y is not 'no'
df$z[df$x != 'no' & df$y != 'no'] <-df$x[df$x != 'no' & df$y != 'no']
# Here I change every row of df$z where df$y is not 'no'. Not sure is this is in your question.
df$z[df$y != 'no'] <-df$y[df$y != 'no']
df
```

Comment: HI Gowachin. Thanks for answering, this is a great start. I ended up creating the new variable in the excel sheet, which fixed it, but it was very tedious. For the sake of the case, there is one issue with your solution. The variable z is suppose to be positive (yes) in all instances where either x or y has a positive answer (anything else than no), so in the example below, there is only one value in z that should be negative, the one that have no in both x and y. Thanks!

Comment: Hi JensMadsen. Thanks for your comment, I've edited my answer to fit your case, hopping it will work now!